# Kibana not identifying field as time-based

Tags: elasticsearch, kibana, java

I'm using java API to index data into ElasticSearch and generate graphs in Kibana.
I have a field named "Event_TS" which holds values of type long (time at which event was created in milliseconds). I could generate Date Histograms using it.
(I'm getting JSON document from a separate method.)

But, when I finally reindexed the whole data, Kibana is not identifying "Event_TS" as time-based anymore and hence I can't generate Date Histograms. How do I resolve this?

Comment: What does your elasticsearch mapping show for that field?  Also note that Kibana will currently only allow you to use one time field per index definition.  https://github.com/elastic/kibana/issues/4312

Comment: @AlainCollins,  it shows 'long'. Earlier also, it was 'long' itself when Kibana was identifying it as time-based (although there were other fields also which were of type 'long' like success_count, failure_count. They are actually of type 'int', but they are getting promoted to 'long' because of the method which indexes objects). So, I have only time field per index definition.

Comment: In my mappings, dates are type "date".  When you define the index pattern, use that date field as the "Time-field name".  That works in Kibana4.